# How to find the three closest distinct units for each of my sites using SQL

Tags: postgresql, query, select

I am trying to locate the three closest distinct units for each of my sites. I have my measured distances as `total_mile`, the starting locations are `from_site_`, and the end locations are `to_unitcod`. However, there are sometimes multiple end locations associated with the same `to_unitcod` that fall within the top three shortest distances, where I need three different units for each site.

The code below is the closest I have gotten so far. What could I add to this that will make it select three different/distinct `to_unitcod` for each `from_site_`? Right now it is pulling the three shortest measured distances between each site and unit, which is good, but I would like it to pull the three shortest distances from three different units (`to_unitcod`).

```
    SELECT *
    FROM
        (
        SELECT nearrank, total_mile, from_site_, to_poiname, to_unitcod, to_unitnam,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY from_site_ ORDER BY total_mile ASC) rn
        FROM public.mytable
        ) X
    WHERE rn<=3
    ORDER BY from_site_;
```

Comment: Please provide create and insert statements (a fiddle would also help) to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please don't upload images here for the reasons outlined in this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530). Plese go to dbfiddle.uk and construct a fiddle with your tables, some sample data and a desired result... Help us to help you!